# How to make a single File Path, regardless of operating system? ex: File.open(path)

Tags: ruby, linux, macos, file, path

I have a program that creates a file on the users computer if it does not exist.
I need to use two different file paths depending on whether they are using Linux or Unix.

Is there one file path to rule them all, or do I need to create two repos, one for Mac and one for Linux?

Error if I use the mac for the linux or vice versa.

> Not a directory @ rb_sysopen - $path (Errno::ENOTDIR)

LINUX

```
coin_file = File.expand_path("../coin/coin.json", __FILE__)
if !File.exists?(coin_file)
    File.open(coin_file, "w+") {|f| f.write("{}") }
end
```

MAC

```
coin_file = File.expand_path("coin/coin.json", __FILE__)
if !File.exists?(coin_file)
    File.open(coin_file, "w+") {|f| f.write("{}") }
end
```

Comment: _"I need to use two different file paths"_ – what does this mean? Do you want to have the file in different locations based on operating system or do you have to use different code to get the same result?

Comment: In the latter case you might want to try building your path based on [`__dir__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Kernel.html#__dir__-method) which returns the current file's absolute directory.

Comment: The Mac is based on BSD Unix, and the file pathes are following the same syntax as Linux. Furthermore, the Ruby file functions are designed in a way that they understand the usual PATH format (with forward slashes) on all platforms. In your case, `expand_path` seems to produce a broken absolute path. In any case, the parameter `__FILE__` does not make sense here. I suggest that for debugging, you print the value of `coin_file`.